# Get notices from Postgresql in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a function in postgres that raises notices while it runs and I see the notices in pgadmin messages tab. I want to run this function using a C# console app. How can I get the notices when I execute the function without setting up a listener for the notice event? I don't care if it is sync or async, I am just interested in getting the info.

I tried saving the notices in a .txt file and it works but in this case I can't edit the function in postgres or any settings.

Comment: You want to get the log files from PostgreSQL.  See https://community.qlik.com/t5/Official-Support-Articles/How-to-find-and-read-the-PostgreSQL-database-logs-after-setting/ta-p/1711547  Here is c# code to do a query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/connect-csharp

Comment: Why do you want this? Implement some kind of "progress" perhaps? Log messages are *not* a valid result type. Especially low-priority messages like INFO or NOTICE which the server may choose to return only once the operation completes. Npgsql itself logs them as DEBUG messages to avoid noise and the performance hit they'd cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Npgsql, notices are logged are received and logged at the DEBUG level already. You can also handle the [Notice event in NpgsqlConnection](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/diagnostics/exceptions_notices.html#postgresql-notices). Notices and log messages in general aren't results though and shouldn't be handled that way. They can be noisy (DEBUG level) and cause a significant performance hit. The server may well decide to delay sending such low-priority messages to clients too:

```
conn.Notice += (_, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Notice.MessageText);
```

Comment: Although your answer is exactly what the documentation says, which I've read, your comment helped me. I wanted to get progress of some sort without altering 5 y.o. pgsql code that raises notices for it's own progress. Thanks!

Comment: @GiorgosDimas you didn't ask that though. You asked something else. That's why someone else downvoted your question and why I asked in the comments why you want this. There are hints in the question that you want to do what's actually a common mistake - trying to use messages as some kind of real-time server notification. There are better solutions for the *actual* problem